# ¿Cómo trazar un marco de datos según el tiempo con el recuento del número de objetos en una fecha determinada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, plotly

Quiero mostrar un gráfico de barras con la hora en el eje x y la suma de los elementos publicados ese día en el eje y.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv(
    "articulos.csv")

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.date), y=???)) # y = count de articulos para cada dia

# Set title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Time series with range slider and selectors"
)

# Add range slider
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Por ejemplo aqui esta el csv:

```
    Date        text        Wind    Solar   Wind+Solar
0   2006-01-01  blabla      NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2006-01-01  blibli      NaN     NaN     NaN
2   2006-01-03  bloblo      NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Con `groupby` se puede primero agrupar por fecha, y después sumar.
Para el plot, la `x` seria el index de cada grupo, y la `y` del resultado principal del `groupby`. Nota que `agrupado.index` tiene cada fecha solo una vez, mientras `df.date` las puede tener múltiples veces.

Si la columna 'Date' incluye horas y minutos, en el `groupby` se puede extraer solo la fecha: `agrupado = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date)['Consumption'].sum()`.

```py
agrupado = df.groupby(['Date'])['Consumption'].sum()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(agrupado.index), y=list(agrupado)))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias y comoc hacer que el resultado principal del groupby sea el count de las lineas que tienen la msma fecha? `df.groupby(df['Date']).count()`?

Comment: Si, `df.groupby(df['Date']).count()` crea una columna en el resultado para cada columna de entrada. Y cuenta el número que no son ´NaN´s.

Comment: ¿Hay algun motivo por que la respuesta no esta marcada como aceptada?